# Use username field instead of email in Oauth 2.0

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0

Hi I would like to ask if its possible to use a username field in the users table instead of email field just to make it the same to the one that I post in the URL. Just to remove confusion because in Postman I use username but it maps to the email field on the table

Here's the screenshot in PostMan:

[image]